# Retrofit Android

Tags: android, retrofit

estoy con un problema para una app que estoy haciendo, que en teoría parece ser simple, pero me esta dando quebraderos de cabeza.

La intención es hacer una conexión REST a una API para recoger sus datos. En este caso para obtener todas las provincias de una comunidad.

El código es el siguiente:

```
private void getPosts() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constantes.API_REST_CITIES_SPAIN)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    CitiesService cs = retrofit.create(CitiesService.class);

    Call< List<Ciudades> > call = cs.getProfile();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Ciudades>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Ciudades>> call, Response<List<Ciudades>> response) {
            for(Ciudades post : response.body()) {
                for (int i=0; i<post.getData().size(); i++){
                    titles.add(post.getData().get(i).getCOM());
                }
            }
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Ciudades>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Algo ha fallado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

public interface CitiesService {
    @GET(Constantes.API_REST_CITIES_SPAIN_COMUNIDADES)
    Call<List<Ciudades>> getProfile();
}
```

Las rutas de la constantes son correctas, pues hago lo mismo mediante URL en el navegador y me da buen resultado.

Este es el log que me sale:

> W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method
>   java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String,
>   boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization
>   request on un-deoptimizable method
>   okhttp3.internal.platform.android.SocketAdapter
>   okhttp3.internal.platform.android.ConscryptSocketAdapter.buildIfSupported()I/zygote64:
>   Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class
>   java.lang.Class:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lorg/conscrypt/ConscryptHostnameVerifier; D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No
>   Network Security Config specified, using platform default
>   Cita en bloque

Comment: Por el log asumo que estas ejecutando la app en un dispositivo android 4.4 o menor, tuve ese problema antes y lo resolvi de la siguiente manera, checa el paquete api de este repo, espero te funcione!
[Ejemplo](https://github.com/DjangoLC/GalleryDemo)

Answer (score 0):

me sucedió exáctamente lo mismo, intenta importando la siguiente dependencia:

```
implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.2.1'
```

¡Con esto me funcionó perfectamente!